# Cannot open database requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user

Tags: sql, база-данных, asp.net, sql-server

Пытаюсь добавить данные в бд. Выдаёт ошибку:

> "При соединении с БД произошла ошибка Cannot open database "F:\AUTOPASS\APP_DATA\AUTO.MDF" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'ADMIN\Денис'. "

Вебконфиг

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;AttachDbFilename=F:\autopass\App_Data\auto.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" />
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\auto.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Строки передачи в бд:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\auto.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    try
    {
        sqlCon.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd_SQL = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Categories(Name) VALUES (@Name)", sqlCon);
        cmd_SQL.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;

        cmd_SQL.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd_SQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Label1.Text = "Добавлен элемент " + TextBox1.Text;
        //Response.Redirect("~/AdminAddCategory.aspx");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = "При соединении с БД произошла ошибка ";
        Label1.Text += ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlCon.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

проверьте есть у ADMIN\Денис разрешение на редактирование файла auto.mdf